# google chart stacking not working

Tags: html, google-visualization

Here is my HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
var jsonDataObj = {
"rows":[
{"c":[{"v":"2001"},{"v":"43"},{"v":"43"}]},
{"c":[{"v":"2002"},{"v":"43"},{"v":"43"}]},
{"c":[{"v":"2003"},{"v":"43"},{"v":"43"}]},
{"c":[{"v":"2004"},{"v":"43"},{"v":"43"}]}
],
"cols":[
{"id":"","label":"Year","type":"string"},
{"id":"","label":"profits","type":"number"}, 
{"id":"","label":"expenses","type":"number"}
]
};
function drawChart() {
var jsonData = jsonDataObj;
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
var options = {
width: 800, height: 480,
//isStacked:true,
title: 'Company Performance'
};
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I enable isStacked option the pictuer shown is completely wrong 
[image]

if I disable it the chart is fine
[image]

Let me know how to get the stacking to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some testings I found the reason of the bug: you defined a strings in data instead of numbers, fixed page below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
var jsonDataObj = {
"rows":[
{"c":[{"v":"2001"},{"v":65},{"v":40}]},
{"c":[{"v":"2002"},{"v":67},{"v":43}]},
{"c":[{"v":"2003"},{"v":80},{"v":35}]},
{"c":[{"v":"2004"},{"v":97},{"v":47}]}
],
"cols":[
{"id":"","label":"Year","type":"string"},
{"id":"","label":"profits","type":"number"}, 
{"id":"","label":"expenses","type":"number"}
]
};


function drawChart() {
var jsonData = jsonDataObj;
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
var options = {
width: 800,
height: 480,
isStacked: true,
title: 'Company Performance'
};
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look at this example https://jsfiddle.net/912jggdw/

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ["Category",    "A", "Total"    ],
          ["Planned",  500,        500       ],
          ["Achieved",  400,       600       ]
        ]);

      var options = {
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        legend: {position: "none"},
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true,
      };


      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be using Google Image Charts.

And it is good because

1) it will work in all browsers including old ones, as it is a picture.

2) You can do Bullet Charts with it, when there is no option to do "Bullet Charts" in new Google Charts, and even the plain Diff Charts styled as "Bar and Column" does not work in latest versions of Firefox (I tried version 39).

Here is great [example](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=110x300&cht=bvs&chco=8DB2E3&chd=t:45&chbh=30&chm=r,ff0000,0,0.495,0.5,1%7Cr,D4D1D1,0,0,0.5%7Cr,F3F3F3,0,0.5,1&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:%7CCriteria%201%7C1:%7C0%7C100%7C200&chxs=0,000000,15):

[image]

Read more about Google Image Charts here:

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/?hl=en